# Toolbar image error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

It's apparently a question that has been asked multiple times, but only has solutions on a case-by-case basis.I am making an aap with toolbar and when i go to second activity i want the toolbar to display icon as well as settings menu but unfortunately toolbar is appearing but icons are not showing also android monitor shows null pointer exception on these lines of code

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

[Error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8TNU.png)

This is my activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.zaina.toolbar.MainActivity">
    <include android:id="@+id/aap_bar" layout="@layout/aap_bar"></include>
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/aap_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.zaina.toolbar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.aap_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu item) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, item);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public  boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
        int id=menuItem.getItemId();
        if(R.id.action_favorite==id){
            startActivity(new Intent(this,aap.class));
            return true;
        }
        if(R.id.action_settings==id){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hey you hit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
}
```

This is my aapbar_xml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:aap="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    aap:Theme="@style/MyCustom"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This is my activity_aap.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.zaina.toolbar.aap">
    <include android:id="@+id/app_bar" layout="@layout/aap_bar"></include>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is aap.java

```
package com.example.zaina.toolbar;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;

public class aap extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_aap);
        Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.aap_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu item) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sub, item);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my menu_sub.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/za"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_chevron_left_black_24dp"
        android:title="left"
        aap:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/zee"
        android:title="sett"
        aap:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: post your log info

Comment: log info pic uploaded by"error pic"at top@ShubhamShukla

Comment: see if my answer resolve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be few reasons of `NullPointException`, try to:

You are probably using a Theme that doesn't support `ActionBar`. 
Trying using this theme:
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"`.

try to catch:

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
{
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

Or, try to change the `id` of app_bar in `aap.java`

Comment: tried you're code but it is giving the same Null pointer exception @W4R10CK

Comment: try to change the id of app_bar in xml for app.java

Answer (score 0):

findViewById method returning null.
Add id attribute to your toolbar

```
android:id="@+id/aap_bar
```

You are also using wrong namespace aap

Use app

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: i've tried youre code now it goes to second activity but does'nt show image and setting icons which is menu_sub.xml?@Shubham Shukla

Comment: use this attribute in your menu file  app:showAsAction="always"